# Session variable cleared in ASP.NET web page

Tags: asp.net, session

I used session variable to store some value in ASP web page. I found that for some of my clients(1%), session variable was cleared during post back.

What might be the reason for session variable to clear? Is there a way to avoid it?

Sample code:

```
If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
    Session("poststring") = "test string"
Else
    TestVariable = Session("poststring")
End If
```

Comment: Have you tested your website on browser with disabled cookies? Also, I am assuming that when you say 1%  clients all are desktop users?

Comment: Dupe likely contains the answer of either app pool recycle, or your own code.

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood, yes all are dektop users.

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood, problem resolved it was due to the "disabled cookies"

Comment: Great to know that problem is resolved